# ¿Es posible inyectar un proveedor/dependencia en una constante de Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Estamos creando una constante en nuestro proyecto desarrollado con ayuda de AngularJS, esto con el fin de evitar código repetido. No obstante, nos surge la duda sobre si es posible inyectar un proveedor o dependencia dentro de esa constante, y la pregunta surge porque quisimos utilizar uno de los atributos para manipular los mensajes con [Angular-Growl](http://janstevens.github.io/angular-growl-2/) y no fue posible. En el caso de [SweetAlert](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) fue posible sin problemas.

```
(function () {
   'use strict';

    angular.module('mytodoApp').constant("appConstant", {
       'FILTRO_TABLAS': [{ name: '5', value: '5' }, { name: '10', value: '10' },
           { name: '20', value: '20' }, { name: '30', value: '30' },
           { name: '50', value: '50' }],
       'MSG_LOADING': function (title) {
           swal({
               title: title,
               allowOutsideClick: false,
               allowEscapeKey: false
           });
       },
       'MSG_SYSTEM_ERROR': function (title, type) {
           swal('Hubo un problema', title, type);
        }
   })
})();
```

En este caso, al inyectar la constante *appConstant* en cualquier controlador, los swal (que son los mensajes generados con SweetAlert) funcionan bien, sin embargo, al añadir esto:

```
'MSG_GROWL_ERROR': function(title) {
  growl.error("<div><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' style='padding-left:15px;font-size: 20px;'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span><strong>Error!</strong>" +title+"</div>");
```

Aparece en la consola del navegador que no se conoce una dependencia llamada *Growl*. Intenté inyectarla en la constante y automaticamente la aplicación explota.

Comment: Hola Cesar, ¿puedes agregar un ejemplo de lo que tienes y la idea de como esperas que quede? No termina de quedar claro tu objetivo. Saludos.

Comment: Listo, he sido más explícito en mi situación.

Comment: Intentaste agregar el módulo? `angular.module('mytodoApp', ['angular-growl'])`

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }.`

Era obvio, de hecho que en el app.js está ya inyectada la directiva.

Comment: claro, Cesar, cuando usas [] en `angular.module` creas un nuevo modulo. Me parece que devconcept te pregunta si estaba importado pero ya contestate que si.

Comment: El código que te da el error está en un bloque `config`?

Comment: No, no estoy usando config, estoy usando constant.

Comment: Tu puedes inyectar una constante en varios lugares. El código está un poco confuso ya que solo es un fragmento de ahí mi confusión y mi pregunta.

Comment: En realidad es un archivo y dentro, un módulo con su constante, no es un fragmento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dice la documentación, no se puede injectar otros servicios en una constante ([fuente](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant)). Lo cual es lógico, pues de otro modo, no seria una constante.

Sin embargo, puede usar un servicio en si. Si quieres evitar que se pueda modificar el objeto `FILTRO_TABLAS`, puedes usar **[`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/freeze)**.

```
angular.service('miservicio', ['growl', function(growl) {
   this.MSG_GROWL_ERROR = function(title) {
        growl.error("<div><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' style='padding-left:15px;font-size: 20px;'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span><strong>Error!</strong>" +title+"</div>");
   }

   this.FILTRO_TABLAS = { constante: 20 };
   Object.freeze(this.FILTRO_TABLAS);
});
```

Comment: Efectivamente rnd, funciona muy bien de esta manera. Habíamos escogido constantes para que no se cambiarán los valores. Nos damos cuenta que esto también evita inyectar dependencias en los controladores y darle esa carga a ese servicio.

Comment: @CésarGómez he editado la respuesta, esta es la rta final ;)

Comment: Es decir, tengo que hacer eso para todas las constantes?

Comment: @CésarGómez puedes poner todas las propiedades que quieras en ese objeto (`{constantes:20, otra:35: otramas:60}`) y todas serán inmutables. Fijate en la documentacion que vincule.

Comment: Listo, ya entendí. Muchas gracias, funciona muy bien. (Y)